# What does "whiteout" mean in a copy-on-write filesystem?

Tags: filesystem

The [manual for aufs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/aufs.5.html) makes several references to something called a "whiteout", but it's not clear to me what this is.

What is a whiteout and why would one exist?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is how the union file system supports deleting from a union where the underlying file to be deleted resides on a read-only file system.

Say you have

- `/bin` (read-only)
- `/usr/bin` (read-only)
- `/home/USERNAME/bin` (read-write)

all union mounted together in `/bin` (read-write).

And you do `rm /bin/ls`.

It would place a whiteout for `ls` in `/home/USERNAME/bin`, which makes it look like `/bin/ls` has been deleted.

See [State of the unionfs](http://lwn.net/Articles/265240/) for a good read and a full explanation.